# Without using the popup window how to edit a particular row in jQuery grid

Tags: c#, sql, jqgrid

I am writing code for doing inline editing in jqgrid. It's working fine in the pop-up mode. But I need the same in the inline mode. Please help me solve this problem. I have been trying to solve it for the past week.

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
            <title></title>
            <script src="JQGridReq/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="JQGridReq/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="JQGridReq/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link href="JQGridReq/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script src="Scripts/json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <div id="topList">
                </div>
                <table id="list">

                </table> <%--for grid--%>
                <div id="pager">

                </div> <%--for paging--%>
            </div>
            </form>

             <script type="text/javascript">


                 $(document).ready(function () {
                     function getCountry() {
                         var country;
                         $.ajax({
                             type: "POST",
                             contentType: "application/json",
                             data: "{}",
                             async: false,
                             url: "Default.aspx/getNational",
                             dataType: "json",
                             success: function (data) {

                                 country = data.d;

                             },

                             error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                 debugger;
                             }

                         });
                         return country;
                     }




                     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         contentType: "application/json",
                         data: "{}",
                         url: "Default.aspx/getEmployee",
                         dataType: "json",
                         success: function (data) {
                             data = data.d;
                             $("#list").jqGrid({
                                 datatype: "local",
                                 colNames: ['', 'Employee Id', 'Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Password', 'Nationality', 'Date of Birth'],
                                 colModel: [
                                {
                                    name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 75, align: 'center', search: false, sortable: false, formatter: 'actions',
                                    formatoptions: {
                                        keys: true,
                                        editformbutton: true,
                                        editOptions: {

                                            recreateForm: true,
                                            reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                                            width: 500,
                                            closeAfterEdit: true,
                                            ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                                            serializeEditData: function (postData) {

                                                var postdata = { 'data': postData };
                                                alert(postData);
                                                return JSON.stringify(postdata);
                                            }
                                        },
                                        delOptions:
                                        {

                                            ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                                            reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                                            onclickSubmit: function (eparams) {
                                                var retarr = {};
                                                var sr = $("#list").getGridParam('selrow');
                                                rowdata = $("#list").getRowData(sr);
                                                retarr = { employeeId: rowdata.employeeId };

                                                return retarr;
                                            },
                                            serializeDelData: function (postdata) {
                                                var postData = { 'data': data };
                                                return JSON.stringify(postData);
                                            }
                                        }                           // we want use [Enter] key to save the row and [Esc] to cancel editing.

                                    }
                                },

                                       { name: 'employeeId', index: 'employeeId', width: 55, stype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 1, colpos: 1 }, editrules: { integer: true } },
                                       { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 90, stype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 1 } },
                                       { name: 'email', index: 'email', width: 90, stype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: true, editrules: { email: true, required: true }, formoptions: { rowpos: 2, colpos: 2 } },
                                       { name: 'phone', index: 'phone', width: 70, align: "right", stype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 0, colpos: 0 } },
                                       { name: 'pwd', index: 'pwd', width: 70, align: "right", stype: 'text', edittype: 'password', sortable: true, editable: true, formoptions: { rowpos: 3, colpos: 2 } },
                                  {
                                      name: 'nationalId', index: 'nationalId', width: 80, align: "right", formatter: 'select', stype: 'select',
                                      editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: getCountry() }, formoptions: { rowpos: 4, colpos: 1 }
                                  },
                                   {
                                       name: 'dateOfBirth', index: 'dateOfBirth', width: 80, align: "right",
                                       edittype: 'text', editable: true,
                                       editoptions: {
                                           dataInit: function (el) {
                                               $(el).datepicker({
                                                   dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                                                   changeMonth: true,
                                                   changeYear: true,
                                               });
                                           }
                                       },
                                       formoptions: { rowpos: 4, colpos: 2 }
                                   }

                                 ],
//this line is used to pass the data into the database
//
                                 data: JSON.parse(data),
                                 rowno: 10,
                                 loadonce: true,
                                 /* multiselect:true,*/
                                 rowlist: [5, 10, 20],
                                 pager: '#pager',
                                 viewrecords: true,
                                 gridview: true,
                                 sortorder: 'asc',
                                 toppager: true,
                                 cloneToTop: true,
                                 altrows: true,
                                 autowidth: false,
                                 hoverrows: true,

                                 height: 300,
                                 /* toolbar: [true, "top"],*/
                                 rownumbers: true,
                                 caption: "Employee Data",
                                 editurl: 'Default.aspx/EditUpdateDel'

                                 /*  ondblClickRow: function(rowid) {
                       $(this).jqGrid('editGridRow', rowid,
                       {recreateForm:true,closeAfterEdit:true,
                        closeOnEscape:true,reloadAfterSubmit:false, width: 500});
                       }*/




                             });


                             $('#list').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
                            {
                                edit: true,
                                add: true,
                                del: true,
                                search: false,
                                searchtext: "Search",
                                addtext: "Add",
                                edittext: "Edit",
                                deltext: "Delete",
                                cloneToTop: true

                            }
                                  , {
                                      //add//
                                      recreateForm: true,
                                      //reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                                      //beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                                      //    $('#tr_employeeId', form).hide();
                                      //},
                                      width: 500,
                                      reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                                      closeAfterAdd: false,
                                      ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                                      serializeEditData: function (postData) {
                                          var postdata = { 'data': postData };
                                          return JSON.stringify(postdata);
                                      }


                                  },
                                  //edit//

    //Here i ham writing a code for doing inline editing in jqgrid. It's working //fine in the pop-up mode.But i need the same in the inline mode.pls help me //solve this problem. I a trying to solve it for the past on week.

                                  {
                                      //recreateForm: true,

                                      //beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                                      //    $('#tr_employeeId', form).hide();
                                      //},
                                      //width: 500,
                                      //reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                                      //closeAfterAdd: false,
                                      //ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                                      //serializeEditData: function (postData) {
                                      //    var postdata = { 'data': postData };
                                      //    return JSON.stringify(postdata);
                                      //}

                                      recreateForm: true,
                                      reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                                      width: 500,
                                      closeAfterEdit: true,
                                      ajaxEditOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },

                                      serializeEditData: function (postData) {
                                          var postdata = { 'data': postData };
                                          return JSON.stringify(postdata);
                                      }


                                  },



                                  {
                                      //delte//
                                      ajaxDelOptions: { contentType: "application/json" },
                                      reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                                      onclickSubmit: function (eparams) {
                                          var retarr = {};
                                          var sr = $("#list").getGridParam('selrow');
                                          rowdata = $("#list").getRowData(sr);
                                          retarr = { employeeId: rowdata.employeeId };

                                          return retarr;
                                      },
                                      serializeDelData: function (data) {
                                          var postData = { 'data': data };
                                          return JSON.stringify(postData);
                                      }


                                  });

                             $("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true });
                             var grid = $("#list");
                             var topPagerDiv = $('#' + grid[0].id + '_toppager')[0];
                             $("#" + grid[0].id + "_toppager_center", topPagerDiv).remove(); /"#list_toppager_center"/
                             $(".ui-paging-info", topPagerDiv).remove();

                             var bottomPagerDiv = $("div#pager")[0];
                             $("#add_" + grid[0].id, bottomPagerDiv).remove();
                             $("#edit_" + grid[0].id, bottomPagerDiv).remove();
                             $("#del_" + grid[0].id, bottomPagerDiv).remove();
                             $("#refresh_" + grid[0].id, bottomPagerDiv).remove();
                             // "#add_list"


                         },

                         error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                             debugger;
                         }
                     });
                 });


            </script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of places in the code which could be better to change, but your main problem is wrong usage of `formatoptions` for `formatter: 'actions'`.

You can read in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:predefined_formatter#predefined_format_types) of the option of `formatter: 'actions'`the following:

> When the editformbutton parameter is set to true the form editing
>   dialogue appear instead of in-line edit. The option editOptions will
>   be used only for the form editing.

You try to use inline editing, so you have to remove `editformbutton: true` property from `formatoptions` first of all.

To serialize the data one should use `serializeRowData` callback *of jqGrid* instead of usage `serializeEditData` callback of *the form editing*

Some common remarks to your code.

1. I recommend you to move the `<script>` part where you create the grid from the `<body>` to the `<head>` part. Alternatively you can remove `$(document).ready(function () {...});` handler. The usage of `ready` for body inside of the body is not good.
2. It seems that `employeeId` is the native id of the data which you load. You can add `key: true` to `employeeId` column or to use `jsonReader: {id: "employeeId" }` (or `jsonReader: {id: 0 }` depend on exact format of input data which you use).
3. You use `data: JSON.parse(data.d)`, where `data` is the parameter of `success` callback. It means that **you made unneeded** JSON serialization in `"Default.aspx/getEmployee"`. Instead of returning `object` you probably convert the object with data to string *manually*. DotNet framework *automatically convert the returned data to JSON. So you should remove manual conversion of returned data to string inside of `"Default.aspx/getEmployee"`. After that you need replace `data: JSON.parse(data.d)` to `data: data.d`. Now you can remove manual `$.ajax` call to the usage of `datatype: "json"` and `url: "Default.aspx/getEmployee"` and to use just `jsonReader: {root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total",  records: "d.records"}`. If you don't use server side paging then you should add `loadonce: true` option additionally

There are some other places to improve the code, but one can't solve all problems at once.